# Firebug style code inspector for iPhone / iPad?

Tags: ios, web-development

Im testing a website ive made and there are some differences in how the site looks on iPhone and iPads compared to desktop browsers (including webkit browsers like Safari and Chrome).

I need have a look at the styes like i can do with Firebug or the Chrome dev tools, but for iPads or iPhones. What are the options for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iPhone/iPad enter Settings, then Safari, go to Developer and turn on Debug Console.
Next, you need to connect your iPhone/iPad to apple computer. Then on computer enter Safari application. In safari enter Development tab and select your device. Web Inspcetor will show up, with code of selected page.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome can now do device emulation:

Open the dev tools.

Get to the emulation tab (I got here by going 'show console', then the emulation tab is under the normal elements inspector).

Now you can chose from a number of different devices, and you can still use the html / css inspector.